# ABC conjecture exceptions

Tags: number-theory, abc-conjecture

I’m working on a simple presentation for a class on the ABC conjecture.
 Nothing too deep. I would like to give an example of a triplet of coprime integers $a, b, c$ such that $$c<\operatorname{rad}(abc)^2$$ and $$c>\operatorname{rad}(abc)^{1.5}$$ Could somebody find such an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture#Computational_results)

$$ q= 1.6299, a=  2, b= 3^{10}·109 , c=23^{5}$$
$$ q= 1.6260, a= 11^2,  b=3^2·5^6·7^3, c=  2^{21}·2^3$$
$$ q=1.6235,  a=19·1307,b=  7·29^2·31^8, c=  2^8·3^{22}·5^4$$
$$ q= 1.5808, a=  283, b=  5^{11}·13^2, c=  2^8·3^8·17^3$$
$$q=  1.5679, a=  1, b=  2·3^7, c=  5^4·7$$

Comment: Oh you're right. Thank you.